# How to integrate `variable-vale` pair date to a dict?

Tags: python

I am processing some `variable = value` style date:

```
data_type = {'Number': ['int','bool','float','complex'],
             'Literal':['str','None','bytes']}
data_struture = {'Sequence':['list', 'tuple','bytearray'],
                 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset'],
                 'Map':'dict'}
.
.
.
```

Atempt to integrate them into a dict with key inoformation meanwhile avoid repeated typing varaibles,
with final outputs as

```
{'data_struture': {'Map': 'dict',
  'Sequence': ['list', 'tuple', 'bytearray'],
  'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']},
 'data_type': {'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes'],
  'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex']}
  .
  .
  .}
```

I tried to solve the problem by encapsulating the raw date to an class as following steps:

First to encapsulate:

```
class FormalLanguage:
    data_type = {'Number': ['int','bool','float','complex'],
             'Literal':['str','None','bytes']}
    data_struture = {'Sequence':['list', 'tuple','bytearray'],
                     'Set': ['set', 'frozenset'],
                     'Map':'dict'}
```

Second to retrieve class's attributes

```
In [135]: x = dict(vars(FormalLanguage))
In [136]: x
Out[136]:
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'FormalLanguage' objects>,
 '__doc__': None,
 '__module__': '__main__',
 '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'FormalLanguage' objects>,
 'data_struture': {'Map': 'dict',
  'Sequence': ['list', 'tuple', 'bytearray'],
  'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']},
 'data_type': {'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes'],
  'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex']}}
```

Third to filter the qualified

```
In [137]: { i:x[i] for i in x if not i.startswith('__')}
Out[137]:
{'data_struture': {'Map': 'dict',
  'Sequence': ['list', 'tuple', 'bytearray'],
  'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']},
 'data_type': {'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes'],
  'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex']}}
```

Finally get the result.

How to integrate them directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
final_dict = {"data_structure":data_struture, "data_type":data_type}
```

Output:

```
{'data_structure': {'Map': 'dict', 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset'], 'Sequence': ['list', 'tuple', 'bytearray']}, 'data_type': {'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes'], 'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex']}}
```

Or, you can pass them via `**kwargs`:

```
def data(**kwargs):
   final_data = kwargs
   print(final_data)

data(data_structure = data_struture, data_stype=data_type)
```

Comment: It works,I get a sudden idea, copy to editor then replace all `=` with `:`  :- :-

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleNamespace`

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
sn = SimpleNamespace(
data_type = {'Number': ['int','bool','float','complex'],
             'Literal':['str','None','bytes']},
data_struture = {'Sequence':['list', 'tuple','bytearray'],
                 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset'],
                 'Map':'dict'}
```

)
It outputs:

```
In [47]: sn
Out[47]: namespace(data_struture={'Sequence': ['list', 'tuple', 'bytearray'], 'Set': ['set', 'frozenset'], 'Map': 'dict'}, data_type={'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex'], 'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes']})
In [48]: vars(sn)
Out[48]:
{'data_struture': {'Map': 'dict',
  'Sequence': ['list', 'tuple', 'bytearray'],
  'Set': ['set', 'frozenset']},
 'data_type': {'Literal': ['str', 'None', 'bytes'],
  'Number': ['int', 'bool', 'float', 'complex']}}
```